# WINJS Timepicker how to

Tags: javascript, winjs

I have a service to which I receive two data (InTime & OutTime). These data are integer value in secs.

For example :

```
{
InTime :  36000,
OutTime : 57600
}
```

In my UI, I am using two TimePicker (WINJS.UI.Timepicker).  In my timepicker I am using a 24 hour clock. I want to show these values in  time picker. The values should be bound to time picker.

For example : In time should show me 10 : 00 and Out Time should show 16:00 in timepicker.

If user changes the value in time picker I should be bale to read that and convert that to seconds format so that I can do a post also.

So I have two problems:

1. How to convert these received time (in seconds to time) so that I can set the time picker value in UI.
2. When user changes, read the value from time picker, convert to seconds so that I can post it.

I have not been able to understand the TimePicker completely (Yes I have seen the samples), so I am having some issues here.

For the conversion, is there any javascript function already available ?

Any help appreciated.

- Girija

Comment: Is that a timestamp?The seconds you get..Can you give more information...

Comment: No it is just an integer number. For example. InTime : 36000 which means 10:00 and OutTime : 57600 which means 16:00 hours. The calculation is 36000/3600 which is 10 hours from 0:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to convert the seconds to time format you can use the following javascript function

```
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    var obj = {
        "h": hours,
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```

To display time in time picker ,you can set it in current property

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.TimePicker" data-win-options="{current='your value'}">
</div>
```

To detect user input and get value from time picker you can you need to register onchange event handler..

```
timePicker.onchange = hourChangeHandler; 

function hourChangeHandler(event) {
    // Insert code here.
    }
```

Once you get the time from user you can convert it to seconds using this function

```
var hms = '02:04:33';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
```

This is to give you a start, you can change the data types and time format as per your requirements..

Comment: Hi, The settings for the TimePicker is : data-win-options="{current='your value'}". But will this take the obj ? Also how would I get the value from Timepicker ? Will it be in HH:mm:ss.

Comment: Try setting a debug point in onchange handler.. find out the format of date from time picker..

Comment: On the changed event if I catch : timepicker.Current, I get value like this : Fri Jul 15 12:09:00 UTC+0530 2011